# Wrong size returned by systemLayoutSizeFittingSize when using multiline label

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, uilabel

I have a custom table cell `MyCell`, that has only 1 multiline label with constraints to the sides. The xib size is  `320 x 280`.
[image]

I am using `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` to calculate cell height based on the content:

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        MyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell"];

        // set cell width = table width
        CGRect rect = cell.frame;
        rect.size.width = CGRectGetWidth(tableView.frame);
        cell .frame= rect;

        // update the text
        cell.mainLabel.text = @"Some multiline text. Some multiline text. Some multiline text. Some multiline text. Some multiline text. Some multiline text. Some multiline text. Some multiline text.";

        [cell setNeedsLayout];
        [cell layoutIfNeeded];

        CGSize size = [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];

        NSLog(@"size %@", NSStringFromCGSize(size)); // {290.5, 117.5}

        return size.height;
    }
```

`MyCell` `layoutSubviews` looks like this

```
- (void) layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    NSLog(@"cell frame %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame)); // {{0, 0}, {375, 280}}
    NSLog(@"self.mainLabel frame %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.mainLabel.frame)); // {{8, 8}, {304, 264}}

    [self.mainLabel updatePreferredMaxLayoutWidth];
}
```

`updatePreferredMaxLayoutWidth` is category that updated `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` if the frame width is not the same as `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`

```
-(void)updatePreferredMaxLayoutWidth {
    if (self.numberOfLines == 0) {
        if ( self.preferredMaxLayoutWidth != self.frame.size.width){
            self.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.frame.size.width;
            [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I run I get output:

```
cell frame {{0, 0}, {375, 280}}
```

Cell size in `layoutSubviews` has the same width as the table view, correct

```
self.mainLabel frame {{8, 8}, {304, 264}}
```

self.mainLabel frame inside layoutSubviews is 304, that is equal to label size inside the xib file. So the label’s frame wasn't updated to the new cell's size. Why?

```
size {290.5, 117.5}
```

Size of `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` that is completely wrong. What I have missed?

Comment: Have you tried to call `[self.superview setNeedsLayout]; [self.superview layoutIfNeeded];` after `[self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];` executed in `updatePreferredMaxLayoutWidth`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Calling

```
[self.contentView layoutIfNeeded];
```

in `layoutSubviews` of the cell, fixed the issue.

Source [Table View Cells With Varying Row Heights](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2014/02/14/table-view-cells-with-varying-row-heights.html)

Answer (score 26):

I solved this problem using [`systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:withHorizontalFittingPriority:verticalFittingPriority:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622623-systemlayoutsizefittingsize).

In my case, I wanted to calculate a cell's height, so I've set the horizontal priority to `UILayoutPriorityRequired` and the vertical one to `UILayoutPriorityFittingSizeLevel`, and it worked:

```
[myView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:mySize withHorizontalFittingPriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired verticalFittingPriority:UILayoutPriorityFittingSizeLevel];
```

Comment: Great answer, only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this class to solve all problems with your UILabel and Auto Layout:

```swift
class UILabelPreferedWidth : UILabel {
    override var bounds: CGRect {
        didSet {
            if (bounds.size.width != oldValue.size.width) {
                self.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
            }
        }
    }

    override func updateConstraints() {
        if (self.preferredMaxLayoutWidth != bounds.size.width) {
            self.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = bounds.size.width
        }

        super.updateConstraints()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No combination that I've tried worked, so I wrote:

```swift
let sizes: [CGSize] = [UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize, UIView.layoutFittingExpandedSize]

for size in sizes {
    let priorities: [UILayoutPriority] = [
        .required,
        .defaultHigh,
        .dragThatCanResizeScene,
        .sceneSizeStayPut,
        .dragThatCannotResizeScene,
        .defaultLow,
        .fittingSizeLevel
    ]

    for horizontalPriority in priorities {
        for verticalPriority in priorities {
            let height = view.systemLayoutSizeFitting(
                size,
                withHorizontalFittingPriority: horizontalPriority,
                verticalFittingPriority: verticalPriority
            ).height

            print("DEBUG: \(size): \(horizontalPriority): \(verticalPriority): \(height)")
        }
    }
}
```

that printed out *(indentations edited for clarity)*:

```js
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1000.0): 0.0
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 750.0):  130.0
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 510.0):  637.3333333333334
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 500.0):  637.3333333333334
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 490.0):  637.3333333333334
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 250.0):  637.3333333333334
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 50.0):   637.3333333333334
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 750.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1000.0): 0.0
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 750.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 750.0):  166.0
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 750.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 510.0):  206.66666666666666
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 750.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 500.0):  206.66666666666666
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 750.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 490.0):  206.66666666666666
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 750.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 250.0):  206.66666666666666
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 750.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 50.0):   206.66666666666666
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 510.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1000.0): 0.0
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 510.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 750.0):  166.0
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 510.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 510.0):  186.33333333333334
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 510.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 500.0):  186.33333333333334
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 510.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 490.0):  186.33333333333334
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 510.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 250.0):  186.33333333333334
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 510.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 50.0):   186.33333333333334
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 500.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1000.0): 0.0
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 500.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 750.0):  166.0
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 500.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 510.0):  186.33333333333334
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 500.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 500.0):  186.33333333333334
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 500.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 490.0):  186.33333333333334
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 500.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 250.0):  186.33333333333334
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 500.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 50.0):   186.33333333333334
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 490.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1000.0): 0.0
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 490.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 750.0):  166.0
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 490.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 510.0):  186.33333333333334
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 490.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 500.0):  186.33333333333334
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 490.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 490.0):  186.33333333333334
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 490.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 250.0):  186.33333333333334
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 490.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 50.0):   186.33333333333334
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 250.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1000.0): 0.0
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 250.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 750.0):  166.0
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 250.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 510.0):  186.33333333333334
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 250.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 500.0):  186.33333333333334
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 250.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 490.0):  186.33333333333334
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 250.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 250.0):  186.33333333333334
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 250.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 50.0):   186.33333333333334
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 50.0):   UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1000.0): 0.0
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 50.0):   UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 750.0):  166.0
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 50.0):   UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 510.0):  186.33333333333334
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 50.0):   UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 500.0):  186.33333333333334
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 50.0):   UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 490.0):  186.33333333333334
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 50.0):   UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 250.0):  186.33333333333334
DEBUG:  (0.0, 0.0):         UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 50.0):   UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 50.0):   186.33333333333334
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1000.0): 10000.0
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 750.0):  10000.0
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 510.0):  10000.0
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 500.0):  10000.0
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 490.0):  10000.0
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 250.0):  186.33333333333334
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 50.0):   186.33333333333334
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 750.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1000.0): 10000.0
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 750.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 750.0):  10000.0
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 750.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 510.0):  10000.0
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 750.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 500.0):  10000.0
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 750.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 490.0):  10000.0
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 750.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 250.0):  186.33333333333334
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 750.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 50.0):   186.33333333333334
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 510.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1000.0): 10000.0
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 510.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 750.0):  10000.0
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 510.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 510.0):  10000.0
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 510.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 500.0):  10000.0
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 510.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 490.0):  10000.0
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 510.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 250.0):  186.33333333333334
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 510.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 50.0):   186.33333333333334
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 500.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1000.0): 10000.0
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 500.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 750.0):  10000.0
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 500.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 510.0):  10000.0
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 500.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 500.0):  10000.0
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 500.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 490.0):  10000.0
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 500.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 250.0):  186.33333333333334
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 500.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 50.0):   186.33333333333334
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 490.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1000.0): 10000.0
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 490.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 750.0):  10000.0
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 490.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 510.0):  10000.0
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 490.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 500.0):  10000.0
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 490.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 490.0):  10000.0
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 490.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 250.0):  186.33333333333334
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 490.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 50.0):   186.33333333333334
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 250.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1000.0): 10000.0
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 250.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 750.0):  10000.0
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 250.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 510.0):  10000.0
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 250.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 500.0):  10000.0
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 250.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 490.0):  10000.0
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 250.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 250.0):  186.33333333333334
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 250.0):  UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 50.0):   186.33333333333334
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 50.0):   UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1000.0): 10000.0
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 50.0):   UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 750.0):  10000.0
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 50.0):   UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 510.0):  10000.0
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 50.0):   UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 500.0):  10000.0
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 50.0):   UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 490.0):  10000.0
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 50.0):   UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 250.0):  186.33333333333334
DEBUG:  (10000.0, 10000.0): UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 50.0):   UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 50.0):   186.33333333333334
```

and because I knew that the height that I'm looking for, having 2 lines of text, is about 200px, it made me figure out that I needed:

```swift
view.systemLayoutSizeFitting(
    UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize,
    withHorizontalFittingPriority: .defaultHigh,
    verticalFittingPriority: .fittingSizeLevel
).height
```

The values make no sense to me, even after reading the documentation, so I couldn't figure it out without the trial & error code.

*(Note that `.dragThatCanResizeScene`, `.sceneSizeStayPut`, `.dragThatCannotResizeScene` and `.defaultLow` also worked, but I decided to use `.fittingSizeLevel` instead, for no meaningful reason.)*